# Is it possible to create flat table from nested json object in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-web-services

I know, it's possible to create `<struct>` from nested JSON, and then query it with SELECT to access nested fields.
But I want to create a flattened table, so every json field, even nested ones are in separated columns.
Can't find proof that it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glue Tables are representation of underlying data structure and I believe, the table structure has to represent exactly how it is stored.

However, we can easily create a view and use it

lets say table `staff` has a struct `info` as
`struct<name:string,staffid:string,email:string>`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW staff_info AS
SELECT info.name as name, info.id as id
FROM staff;

SELECT * FROM staff_info limit 10
```

Comment: So, i have to create usual <struct> table, and, then create a flat view from the table?